# Singleton usage

Tags: design-patterns

Is singleton a design pattern or a design antipattern?

From here http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/notes/, it said
'Globals and singletons are already well-known as a design antipattern, but they have an interesting additional cost.'

But the GoF book said singleton a design pattern.

So can you please tell me when does using singleton is NOT okay?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who needs singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The singleton is a design pattern.

However, since it is one of the simplest, it is also one that is most abused and in that sense, a design anti-pattern.

The difficulties in writing testable code that uses singletons is another reason people consider it to be an anti-pattern.

A singleton should only be used when you *must* have one instance of the class running in the application space. That is, when you have to *guarantee* that is can only be one such instance.